# Error creating a new Azure Resource Group or App service Plan/ Location

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

While creating a new Resource Group or app service plan/ location on new Azure Management portal, I get the following error.

> Error submitting the deployment request. Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: The provided location 'Central India' is not permitted for subscription. List of permitted regions is 'eastasia,southeastasia,eastus,eastus2,westus,northcentralus,southcentralus,centralus,northeurope,westeurope,japaneast,japanwest,brazilsouth'. Please contact support to change your supported regions.

This is when I try & select any Indian reagions for the service. I've tried with Central India, West India & South India.

What's wrong? Are Indian regions allowed to be selected for creating new resource groups or app plans? Is this something to have with my subscription? Can I change my existing Resource group's region?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks 
Supreet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, Azure DCs are not open for general consumption in India. Right now only EA and some other hand-picked customers have their subscriptions enabled to make use of India DCs.

So in short, your Subscription is not enabled for creation of the resources in India DC. You will just have to wait till the time they open the DCs here in India for general public (or in other words `Pay As You Go` subscription).

Quoting from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/regions/:

> The India regions are available to volume licensing customers and
>   partners with a local enrolment in India. The India regions will open
>   to direct online Azure subscriptions in 2016.

Comment: Well that sums it up. Thank you for the update Sir :) do we have any possible ETA on when they are planning to role it out to general public?

Comment: Reading the footnote here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/regions/, it is sometime in 2016. Quoting from the page: `The India regions are available to volume licensing customers and partners with a local enrolment in India. The India regions will open to direct online Azure subscriptions in 2016.`